# Your Cloud Firestore database has insecure rules - flutter firebase db

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I developed a flutter app,
I use Firebase as my DB, which means that any user can write and read from my DB,

I'm getting the following email every couple of hours.

```
[Firebase] Your Cloud Firestore database has insecure rules

    We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:
any user can read your entire database
any user can write to your entire database
```

Which is exactly what I want, since I want my app to be available to unregistered users.

Did I missed something? is my app is actually insecure?

The access to the DB is done through the app with filters only user specific data.

Is there a way to make my more secure, and keeping it available for unregistered users?

I also not sure why allowing only registered user will make it insecure, since any one can register to the app with a click of a button.

Please shed some light on this issue.

Comment: You have to realize that those messages are telling you that anyone on the internet can very easily write any and all data in the database, potentially causing you total data loss, or an extremely high bill.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @DougStevenson Of course not, do you know how to set it up with Firebase, so that also unregistered user can use the app?

Comment: What exactly are you allowing the registered users to do? Are they allowed to delete the documents?

Comment: The firebase acts as my DB, just like any other DB that I would use in the Backend, similar to an SQL - the user can do any CRUD operation.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need to learn how to use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).  A full discussion is beyond the scope of a single answer, but you should know that security rules allow you to specify who (signed in through Firebase Auth) can read and write which documents and collections.  Not using security rules at all is a massive security hole.

Comment: So basically your are saying that it is not possible to use Firebase in a secure way for unregistered users?

Comment: Not unless you want to pay the costs of a malicious person who is willing to read and write anywhere.  This is the reason why you are getting alerts.

Comment: But a malicious person can easily register to the app and do just the same, so I don't understand how is it more secure?

Comment: They don't have to register through your app directly.  They can use the REST API open to the public.  It's actually very easy - all they have to know is the config for your project, which is necessarily public.  There is a lot of information about this - I suggest doing some research.  Security rules is the only way to secure a project where you allow direct access from the client, and you can use Firebase Auth to at least limit what an individual user can do.  For more security, make the authenticated user go through a backend instead, and check their creds there.

Comment: AFIAK, the api is not public, it is open only to registered apps, i.e. in the app console I create apps and only those app can access the api. please correct me if this is not the case

Comment: No, the API is public.  It's accessible to anyone.  Even if auth is required by security rules, all they have to do is provide an auth token, which is their privilege as an authenticated user.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api

Comment: So you are saying even if auth is required by security the api is not secure?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that at all.  I'm saying that users are free to invoke the auth API endpoints with their own credentials in order to get a Firebase auth token.  You determine what you want that user to be able to do in your rules.

Comment: I understand now, thanks - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&feature=emb_title

Answer (score 1):

The video in the following documentation explain it in a very simple way
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#writing_rules

The bottom line is that you must auth your users, and then use security rules for filtering the data, inorder for your data to be secured.

Using insecure rule should be done only for testing s